# How do I run LibreOffice --headless on a Mac when connecting over ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh, libreoffice, headless, launchd

I'm using `soffice --headless` to test a LibreOffice extension from the command line. This works great on Linux, but when I ssh into our macos test server, it doesn't start at all, just hangs with

```
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to 
the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
```

Is there any way around this? I'm seeing references to `launchd` and things like https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/SystemContexts.html but they seem like they require changes to LibreOffice itself.

Answer (score 0):

The nice people in `#libreoffice-dev` on irc.freenode.net said that a workaround might be that someone has to log in to the graphical UI at least once for this to work. By following

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleRemoteDesktop

(well, screen sharing was already on in my case) and simply logging in with `remmina`, I was able to run `soffice --headless` and test the extension on macos :-)